# What are the performance consequences of different isolation levels in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, transactions, archiving

I am writing an archival script (in Python using psycopg2) that needs to pull a very large amount of data out of a PostgreSQL database (9.4), process, upload and then delete it from the database.

I start a transaction, execute a select statement to create a named cursor, fetch N rows at a time from the cursor and do processing and uploading of parts (using S3 multipart upload). Once the cursor is depleted and no errors occurred, I finalize the upload and execute a delete statement using the same conditions as I did in select. If delete succeeds, I commit the transaction.

The database is being actively written to and it is important that both the same rows get archived and deleted and that reads and writes to the database (including the table being archived) continue uninterrupted. That said, the tables being archived contain logs, so existing records are never modified, only new records are added.

So the questions I have are:

What level of isolation should I use to ensure same rows get archived and deleted?

What impact will these operations have on database read/write ability? Does anything get write or read locked in the process I described above?

Answer (score 2):

You have two good options:

1. Get the data with

   ```
   SELECT ... FOR UPDATE
   ```

   so that the rows get locked. Then the are guaranteed to be there when you delete them.
2. Use

   ```
   DELETE FROM ... RETURNING *
   ```

   Then insert the returned rows into your archive.

The second solution is better, because you need only one statement.

Nothing bad can happen. If the transaction fails for whatever reason, no row will be deleted.

You can use the default `READ COMMITTED` isolation level for both solutions.

Comment: Can I use a named cursor with the second approach? The amounts of data I am working with are huge, I cannot safely download everything and then archive, it has to be done in parts.

The first approach doesn't seem to guarantee that rows inserted while I am processing do not alter the results of the later query.

Comment: Then it is best to use a cursor with `DELETE FROM tab WHERE CURRENT OF c`, where c is the cursor. This can be used with the first approach. Unfortunately the second approach cannot be used with a cursor.

Comment: I am currently fetching data in chunks of a hundred thousand rows at a time. Is there a way to adapt the "WHERE CURRENT" approach to fetching/deleting multiple rows at a time?

Comment: It looks like I am going to have to do this in software. I can force ordering by primary key on the select and use auto-incremented primary key to mark a specific place in the table as the cutoff point for the delete.

Comment: There is `FETCH NEXT n FROM c`.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am using right now. I am just not sure how to use it in conjunction with `DELETE FROM t WHERE CURRENT OF c`

Comment: Um, I didn't think. Well, either you fetch the cursor row by row, or you can find a way to use the `DELETE ... RETURNING *` approach in batches by adding additional conditions so that each batch is small enough; for example a date range.